# How to replace part of text but not touching anything else

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace

I'm trying to edit some text on YouTube channel pages and I want to trim off the subscribers part of the subscriber count. (E.g. 256 subscribers ----> 256). I'm a noob at programming (especially in JS) and haven't found any answers that fit what I wanted. I have a small HTML element that I want to edit with JavaScript to trim off the subscribers part and not touching the numbers. `<yt-formatted-string id="subscriber-count" class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer" aria-label="2.24 million subscribers">2.24M subscribers</yt-formatted-string>`
And I have tried this: `var get=document.getElementById('test'); var str=get.innerHTML; document.write(str.replace("Rindan's","TestNAme"));`
But it instead deleted the whole page and left the number in without the subscribers string so semi-success. Can anyone help me get this reliably working? Sorry for the weird formatting, the text editor for stackoverflow isn't great.

Comment: "*But it instead deleted the whole page*" this is what `document.write` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set innerHtml of the element without writing `document`.

```
  var get=document.getElementById('subscriber-count'); 
  var str=get.innerHTML; 
  get.innerHTML = str.replaceAll("subscribers","");
```

Something like this https://codepen.io/mikhail-vnukov/pen/QWvbeeW

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. It will replace the subscribers word with empty string. Then update the innerHTML with the new string.

`document.write()` will write in the whole document and replace the full page.

```js
var elem=document.getElementById('subscriber-count'); 
var str=elem.innerHTML; 
elem.innerHTML = str.replace("subscribers","");
```

```html
<yt-formatted-string id="subscriber-count" class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer" aria-label="2.24 million subscribers">2.24M subscribers</yt-formatted-string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for a way to "256 subscribers" and be left with 256 in number format.

You could use a regex replace anything that is nothing a number with an empty string then convert it with parseInt like so:

```
const str = "256 subscribers";
const numberStr = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
const number = parseInt(numberStr);
console.log(number); // 256
```